# OpenServer PhpMyAdmin ошибка при открытии сайта http://127.0.0.1/openserver/phpmyadmin/index.php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

ошибка:
"Trait 'Symfony\Contracts\Service\ServiceLocatorTrait' not found in D:\OpenServer\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ServiceLocator.php on line 29"

Фото:
[image: Вот сама страница]